# Removing and Add Indexes in Lucene Index

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I have a Created Lucene Index over some documents and storing this index in a folder.

Now i want to update this Index like

1- Deleting subset of documents from Lucene Index

2- Adding more documents to Lucene Index

How is this possible ? Do i have to create Lucene Index over complete documents again?

Thanks

Comment: I am using Lucene.Net which is Version 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know which version of Lucene you are using, but assuming you are using Java and version 4.0+, you should open `IndexWriter` with [`APPEND`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.html) mode, configured in [`IndexWriterConfig`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriterConfig.html). If you are using .net, there should be a close counterpart.

Comment: How can i delete subset of documents from Lucene Index?

Comment: Recent version of Lucene/Java [`IndexWriter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html) has two `deleteDocuments` methods based either on `Term` or `Query`.